# two uri patterns with one controller

Tags: angularjs

I want to have a url with two different patterns for instance:

```
http://127.0.0.1:27469/views/Home.html#/forcast
```

and

```
http://127.0.0.1:27469/views/Home.html#/forcast/7
```

As you can see, I in the second uri i send a parameter to server too. To do this, I have made this routing

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider

    .when('/forcast',{
        templateUrl:'forcast.html',
        controller:'forcastController'
    });
    when('/forcast/:days',{
        templateUrl:'forcast.html',
        controller:'forcastController'
    })

});
```

But i got an error like:

```
Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error
```

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not properly chaining the function calls. You are closing out the first .when() with a semi-colon. Additionally, you are missing the period before the second when(). You will also run into into an issue where all of your requests will fall into the route without a parameter, switch the order around for the routes so that when a parameter is provided, it will land in the correct route.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider

    .when('/forcast/:days',{
        templateUrl:'forcast.html',
        controller:'forcastController'
    })
    .when('/forcast',{
        templateUrl:'forcast.html',
        controller:'forcastController'
    });
});
```

Another recommendation, rather than declaring 2 routes here, you can specify days as an optional parameter:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider

    .when('/forcast/:days?', {
        templateUrl: 'forcast.html',
        controller: 'forcastController'
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your syntax.  You have a semicolon after the first when, should be a period.  Like this:

```js
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider

    .when('/forcast',{
        templateUrl:'forcast.html',
        controller:'forcastController'
    })
    .when('/forcast/:days',{
        templateUrl:'forcast.html',
        controller:'forcastController'
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

This kind of error appears when you fail to load some module!

Make sure you add `ng-route.js` to your html:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.min.js">
```